# CakePHP You don't have permission to access /app/webroot/ on this server

Tags: php, cakephp, permissions, chmod

I have a problem with CakePHP. I downloaded CakePHP and unzip framework to my project folder: ProjectCake. Then run my site(localhost): conrad.lh .The browser display: 
You don't have permission to access /app/webroot/ on this server.

Here are my files:
/etc/apache2/ste-available/default

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost    
    DocumentRoot /home/conrad/Desktop/projects_java/ProjectCake

    <Directory /home/conrad/Desktop/projects_java/ProjectCake>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

/etc/apache2/site-available/conrad.lh

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName conrad.lh    
    DocumentRoot /home/conrad/Desktop/projects_java/ProjectCake

    <Directory /home/conrad/Desktop/projects_java/ProjectCake>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Most likely, the user running the web server does not have read access to your desktop (or even your user home directory).

Comment: Since this is an Apache issue (rather than a Cake or PHP issue) you may receive better assistance at http://webmasters.stackexchange.com .

Comment: I try delete CakePHP and create simple php file and it works so I think the problem is in CakePHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's most likely a permissions issue. You need to give whatever user the web server is running as read (and possibly write) permissions.

As a temporary and **unsecure** option, run the following command on your project folder to verify that the issue is caused by a filesystem permissions restriction:

```
chmod 777 ProjectCake -R
```

Comment: 777 is writeable for everyone, for security reasons better try 755 for folders and 644 for files.

Comment: If he did use 755 and whatever process was trying to write to the file didn't OWN the file, he'd still have issues. And I did mention that it wasn't a secure option.